# Delete objects from NSManagedObjectContext from another method

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to delete all the objects, but I can't seem to make it work. I know there is other questions for this kind of question, but they are not helpful. What I want is to delete all the objects in section and fixture entity in this method.

```
- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {    
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

This is where I save and fetch my objects in another method.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

for (int i=0; i <=fixtures.count-1; i++) {

    fixture = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Fixture" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fixture setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[fixtures objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"]] forKey:@"date"];
    [fixture setValue:[[fixtures objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"time"] forKey:@"time"];
    [fixture setValue:[[fixtures objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"home"] forKey:@"home"];
    [fixture setValue:[[fixtures objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"away"] forKey:@"away"];
    [fixture setValue:[[fixtures objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"league"] forKey:@"league"];
}

for (int i=0; i <=sections.count-1; i++) {
    lolSection = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Section" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [lolSection setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[sections objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"]] forKey:@"date"];
}

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Fixture"];
self.theFixtures = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Section"];
self.theSection= [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
NSArray* reverseTheArray = [[self.theSection valueForKey:@"date"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
reversedArray = [[reverseTheArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what have you tried so far?

As per the documentation.

> Deleting a managed object is straightforward. You simply send its
>   managed object context a `deleteObject:` message, passing the object you
>   want to delete as the argument.

In other words, using a valid context you shoul say

```
[aValidContext deleteObject:managedObjectYouWantToDelete];
```

About your question, you need to

1. Setup a fetch request to grab the `Fixture` items
2. Loop the results (an `NSArray`) and perform the deletion

For example

```
NSFetchRequest* request = // create the request here...

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [aValidContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil) {
    // Deal with error...
} else {
    // loop the array performing deleteObject
}

// save to persistent store
```

Remaining code is left for exercise ;)

**Edit 1**

Reading again your question, what is the relationship between `Section` and `Fixture`? If they are separated entities, you should perform previous steps also for `Section`s.