# Check Core Data for results and delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I need to create a method for my Core Data. This method should check wether there is any results in the entities `Section` and `Fixture`s. If there are then delete all og the objects in them.

How can I do this? I've tried this, but does not do anything.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *numberOfFixtures = [NSEntityDescription
                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Fixture"
                inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Fixture" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
self.theFixtures = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

for (numberOfFixtures *fixture in self.theFixtures) {
    [context deleteObject:fixture];
}

NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

Comment: You've already added a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629959/delete-objects-from-nsmanagedobjectcontext-from-another-method. It's the same!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Fixture" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
 self.theFixtures = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

 for (NSManagedObject *fixture in self.theFixtures) {
     [context deleteObject:fixture];
 }
 NSError *error;
 [context save:&error];
```

Comment: `[context save:&error];` inside the loop is bad idea.

Comment: Fixtures *fixture. Fixtures what should that be the fetchRequest?

Comment: @user3423384 Assumes `Fixture ` is the `NSManagedObject` subclass and `self.theFixtures` is the array returned by `context` on execution of fetchRequest.

Comment: Invalid operand to binary expression ('NSManagedObject *' and 'NSManagedObject *')

Comment: @user3423384 did you used the updated code? if not please see the edit.

Comment: Yes look at the code i've updated in the question. This is what i have and i get Invalid operand to binary expression ('NSManagedObject *' and 'NSManagedObject *')

Comment: What is your `NSManagedObject` subclass name?

Comment: I'm not using a subclass.

Comment: use  for (Fixture *fixture in self.theFixtures) instead of for (numberOfFixtures *fixture in self.theFixtures)